# Regex: find a number in parentheses

Tags: python, regex

I would like to be able to match off the number 919445504 from the following string:

"1708220416 bytes total (919445504 bytes free)"

The best I've managed to come up with is `\(\d+`
but am stomped on how to remove the (

Comment: Can you explain the criteria used to identify the number?

Comment: You could use a capturing group `\((\d+)[^)]*\)` https://regex101.com/r/quSZ8v/1

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
import re
text = "1708220416 bytes total (919445504 bytes free)"

#First match
m = re.search(r'\([^()]*?(\d+)[^()]*\)', text)
if m:
    print( m.group(1) )
# => 919445504

# All matches, one number per parentheses
text = "1708220416 bytes total (919445504 bytes free) (345 bytes free)"
print (re.findall(r'\([^()]*?(\d+)[^()]*\)', text))
# => ['919445504', '345']

# All matches, all number per parentheses
text = "1708220416 bytes total (919445504 12345) (345 2345)"
print ([num for x in re.findall(r'\([^()]*\)', text) for num in re.findall(r'\d+', x)])
# => ['919445504', '12345', '345', '2345']
```

See [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/qrXxwo)

**Pattern details**

- `\(` - a `(` char
- `[^()]*?` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` as few as possible
- `(\d+)` - Capturing group 1: 1 or more digits
- `[^()]*?` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` as many as possible
- `\)` - a `)` char